# aapt Tool failed android-res.jar not found. when building in flex 4.6 to android tablet

Tags: android, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.6

I keep getting this error when I try to package to my android device. I have moved the aapt.exe, adb.exe, adbWinApi.dll, adbWinUsbApi.dll and the dx.jar to the appropriate places and the original error of the device not being recognized is gone and now I am hitting the following error below. I have searched for a solution but nothing pertains to this exact problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Also before anyone asks the android-res.jar is in the folder and has been updated with the latest sdk.

Following is this error:

Error occurred while packaging the application:

> aapt tool failed:ERROR: Asset package include 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0\lib\android\lib\resources\android-res.jar' not found.